# How do I identify this power transistor? Markings 042R5NT EW1A5NA

Tags: transistors, identification

I took this transistor out from an DC to AC pure sine wave inverter and tried to Google the markings written on it: 042R5NT, EW1A5NA; but couldn't find anything.

[image: photo of component]

I suspect that it is a power MOSFET but I have no way of confirming it. Do these markings have any specific pattern or meanings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SL symbol matches that for Silan Microelectronics.

The 042R5NT marking makes it likely a SVT042R5NT, which is a 40 V N-Channel MOSFET.

[DATASHEET](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2109180930_Hangzhou-Silan-Microelectronics-SVT042R5NT_C2897719.pdf)